# On running the program with >python cmdArguments.py contacts.txt 1 why does it throw an Index error"?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

contacts.txt:

```
Amit,Shah,+9800123456

Pramit,Singh,+9801345678

Shalini,Shah,+9801341876
```

I want to output the second column.

My code is :

```
import sys
li = sys.argv
print(li)
fileName = li[1]
column = int(li[2])
try:
    with open(fileName) as f_obj:
        line = f_obj.readline().strip().split(",")
        while line:
            print(line[column])
            line = f_obj.readline().strip('\n').split(",")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

OUTPUT:

```
D:\6th Sem\Python>python cmdArguments.py contacts.txt 1

['cmdArguments.py', 'contacts.txt', '1']

Shah

Singh

Shah

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "cmdArguments.py", line 10, in <module>

  print(line[column])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur in 3 cases:

1. There are empty lines in the `contacts.txt` file which means `split(',')` would produce an empty list and you are trying to access some index of this list.
2. There are not as many elements in the line as you are trying to access with `line[column]` e.g. if a line contains only `Pramit` and you are trying to access index 1.
3. You have reached the end of file.

From the traceback, it seems you have hit #3 above. You can see, if there is need to handle #1 and #2 depending on the possibility of data format in the `contacts.txt` file.

For #3, you need to detect if you have reached end of file. Right now, `line = f_obj.readline().strip().split(",")` will always produce a list. Once you hit end of file, `line` will be empty list and `while line:` will still evaluate to `True`. So you need to check for `f_obj.readline()` first.

The modified code would look like:

```py
import sys
li = sys.argv
print(li)
fileName = li[1]
column = int(li[2])
try:
    with open(fileName) as f_obj:
        line = f_obj.readline()
        while line:
            lineList = line.strip('\n').split(",")
            print(lineList[column])
            line = f_obj.readline()
            if not line:
                # Reached end of file
                break
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```